# How to connect to Snowflake from Azure Data Factory if Snowflake using RSA Key authentication?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I am using Azure function app to connect to Snowflake and running procedure. But instead I would like to create a Linked service in Azure Data Factory and establish connection with Snowflake.
I don't have password for user name to login to Snowflake but I have RSA Key. These values are stored in Azure Key Vault.
Is there any way to connect to Snowflake using RSA key via Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 0):

RSA is not supported in ADF at this time . Request you to please raise a feature request from the ADF portal itself .

[image]